how to connect to an azure artifacts feed and publish maven artifacts using gradle
how to connect to an azure artifacts feed and publish maven artifacts using gradle from my yaml azure pipeline, i want to publish my artifact in azure artifact such that my maven central dependenceis gets stored in a feed called "GradleBinaries" and SNAPSHOT gets stored in a fifferent feed called "CustomArtifacts".... i dont have setting.xml file  ... if anyone can help i would appreciate it
i have tried implementing the method mentioned in official document but it didn't work out

To publish a maven package using Gradle in your pipeline, you can refer to the following steps:

Add the Maven Settings plugin to your build.gradle file as follows:

plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id "net.linguica.maven-settings" version "0.5"
    id 'maven-publish'
}


Add the following section to your build.gradle file in both the repositories and publishing.repositories containers.

maven {
    url 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<ORGANIZATION_NAME>/<PROJECT_NAME>/_packaging/<FEED_NAME>/maven/v1'
    name '<FEED_NAME>'
    credentials {
        username = "AzureDevOps"
        password = System.getenv("SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN")
    }
    authentication {
        basic(BasicAuthentication)
    }
}

This is my sample build.gradle for your reference:
plugins {
    // Apply the java-library plugin for API and implementation separation.
    id 'java-library'
    id "net.linguica.maven-settings" version "0.5"
    id 'maven-publish'
}

publishing { 
    publications { 
        myPublication(MavenPublication) { 
            groupId 'org.gradle.sample' 
            artifactId 'my-gradle-lib' 
            version '1.0.0'             
        } 
    } 

    // Repositories to publish artifacts 
    repositories { 
        maven {
            url 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<ORGANIZATION_NAME>/<PROJECT_NAME>/_packaging/<FEED_NAME>/maven/v1'
            name '<FEED_NAME>'
            credentials {
                username = "AzureDevOps"
                password = System.getenv("SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN")
            }
            authentication {
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
            }
    }
    } 
} 

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<ORGANIZATION_NAME>/<PROJECT_NAME>/_packaging/<FEED_NAME>/maven/v1'
        name '<FEED_NAME>'
        credentials {
                username = "AzureDevOps"
                password = System.getenv("SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN")
            }
        authentication {
            basic(BasicAuthentication)
        }
}
}
...
}


Use Gradle@3 to publish your package and pass password via environment variable SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN.

trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: Gradle@3
  env:
    SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
  inputs:
    gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
    tasks: 'publish'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false
    spotBugsAnalysis: false



Then the package will be published to my target feed as shown below:



what about maven central dependencies ? i want to store them in a different feed as well ?

What do you mean by saying "maven central dependenceis"? In this ticket, your question is how to connect to an azure artifacts feed and publish maven artifacts using gradle, which has been answered above.

yeah i know ,and i am thankful for that  but please read the entire description , you have answered half the question

Can you explain my maven central dependenceis gets stored in a feed called "GradleBinaries" and SNAPSHOT gets stored in a fifferent feed called "CustomArtifacts". in more detail? Do you want to build and publish different maven packages to different artifact feeds in the same pipeline? Or you want to do something else?
